# If $X$ is an irreducible algebraic variety, can it contain a proper closed subvariety of the same dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My definition of dimension is the increasing chain of irreducible subvarieties. So clearly if $Y \subset X$ is an irreducible proper subvariety of $X$ it must be of lower dimension. But what if I don't know whether $Y$ is irreducible, only closed?

It seems true if I think of a $X$ being a surface but I am pretty ignorant in this field. I also am only interested in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ as the field.

Comment: Well, the dimension of a closed subset $Y$ of $X$ is the maximum of the dimensions of its irreducible components (which are themselves closed in $X$) so it must still be lower than the dimension of $X$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you very much! I thought it would be obvious but I am always uncertain about this topic.

Comment: @Mindlack would you care to record your answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adivsed, I’m turning my comment into an answer.

If $X$ has finite dimension (for instance for just about any definition of algebraic variety) and $Y \subset X$ is a proper closed subset, then the dimension of $Y$ is the *maximum* of the dimensions of its irreducible components $Z$. All these irreducible components are proper closed irreducible subsets of $X$ so have a lower dimension. Thus the dimension of $Y$ is less than the dimension of $X$.